# Validate sequential number and characters in select regexp

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I need to validate a serial number of chassis that It doesn't have sequential number or characters like this:

```
Serial number       Validate
1234567890          true
aaaaaaaaaa          true
aaabbbcccd          true
123abc4567          true
22aabb3398          true
abcdefghij          true
13er4t691d          false
vc-376t65e          false
```

But only different chars and numbers.

I've tried with some like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR ('1088', '^(?!.*?([\w])\1).+') FROM dual;
```

But returns 0 in validation.

Comment: Oracle regex engine does not support lookarounds (and that is just one problem with the regex).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I hacked up that would do this:

```
create or replace function f2 (mystring varchar2) return varchar2 is
  strlen number;
  curchar char(1);
  nextchar char(1);
  validate varchar2(5);
begin
  select 'false' into validate from dual;
  select length(mystring) - 1 into strlen from dual;
  for loopindex in 1..strlen
  loop
    select substr(mystring, loopindex, 1) into curchar from dual;
    if curchar between '0' and '9' or curchar between 'a' and 'z' or curchar between 'A' and 'Z' then
      select substr(mystring, loopindex + 1, 1) into nextchar from dual;
      if ascii(nextchar) - ascii(curchar) between 0 and 1 then
        select 'true' into validate from dual;
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return validate;
end;


SQL> select f2('abcdefghij') c1, f2('vc-376t65e') c2 from dual;

C1         C2
---------- --------------------
true       false
```

It works for all your examples above.

One caveat just because I noticed:  The above assumes the following character is not sequential *ascending*.  Your last example contains both '76' and '65' which are sequential but descending.  If this is intended to allow this, great.  If you also want to flag this type of example, change the if statement above to the following:

```
if abs(ascii(nextchar) - ascii(curchar)) between 0 and 1 then
```

This will return true if any characters are one more than, equal to, or one *less* than the previous character.